# Python: returning a value and calling a separate function at the same time?

Tags: python, function, flask, return, slack

I need to return an http 200 OK status code at the end of a function while also calling a separate function to execute. If I return them at the same time, only the function executes and the http 200 ok never goes through. If one is placed before the other, the second will never execute.

This is my current return statement:

```
return (make_response("", 200), listener())
```

Where make_response() sends the http 200 OK status through my Flask app, and the listener starts a loop to listen for a keyword in Slack.

Comment: You'll need to use a thread or some other concurrency technique.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? This looks like it could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keyword `return` needs the results from the function `listener` to return, it will only execute when the `listener` function has finished

Otherwise what would the `return` command return? One of the thinks you asked it to return is the results of the `listener` function....